# Connecting DataStage and SAS

Tags: sas, stage, datastage

I'm using Datastage 11.3 and I need to call a SAS process from DataStage. My question is: Datastage and SAS need to be installed in the same server? What if these tools are not installed in the same place? Thanks!

PD: sorry for my english :s

Answer (score 1):

The term "process" is not clear. You mean a SAS Program.

A SAS program is stored in a folder.

You can include a program in SAS using this command :

```
%include "c:\mysasprogram.sas";
```

If the program is in another folder on another server, you can use the server as a sharedrive in your network and use %include command.

```
%include "\\IPSERVER\Folder\mysasprogram.sas";
```

If you need to get data from datastage,

You can use SAS ODBC to connect to an external database.

```
LIBNAME  libref informix <connection-options> <LIBNAME-options>;
```

For example with Oracle :

```
LIBNAME Library_name ORACLE  PATH=sid_name  SCHEMA=”schema name”  USER=user_name  PASSWORD=”password”;
```

Another example with Sybase :

```
libname dwh ODBC required="DRIVER=Sybase IQ;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=db;SERVER=server.ip.com,1433" schema=DBO access=READONLY;
```

Comment: I think the OP is talking about using DataStage to drive things, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like DataStage is going to "run" the SAS executable, so it either needs to be on the same server or needs to be accessible from that server (and executable, so if this is Windows it needs to be installed, and if it's Linux/Unix the paths etc. need to be set up properly) in order to run.

If you're going to do something more complex than that, I think you're out of the "programmer" zone and in the server configuration zone - not really StackOverflow material.

You can read about how to configure this in the [DataStage documentation on configuring your system to use SAS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.adref.doc/topics/t_deeadvrf_Configuring_Your_System_to_Use_the_SAS_Interface_Oper.html).